# Why are there mainly entries of already uninstalled programs in the Console?

Tags: console

When I look into Console (/Applications...), I see a lot of entries that talk about programs I have uninstalled a long time ago, for instance

```
01.08.12 10:31:29   com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[206
(de.novamedia.NML2NDeviceObserver[58300])
posix_spawn("/Applications/launch2net/launch2net.app/Contents/
MacOS/NML2NDeviceObserver.app/Contents/MacOS/NML2NDeviceObserver", ...):
No such file or directory
```

The "launch2Net" was uninstalled some years ago! The same thing for "Carbon Copy Cloner", a program I tested some time ago... how can I avoid the causes for those entries? Is there a cleanup?

Comment: How did you uninstall them? Maybe this program has an uninstaller, and should not just be dragged to the Trash?

Comment: I cannot remember :-) Maybe I used the uninstaller, maybe not... nevertheless, the entries are there ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trying to start the nonexistent apps.

From the console entry `com.apple.launchd.peruser.502` we know it's trying to start on behalf of user (instead of system or administrator) that has UID 502.

You can get particular user's account name with `id -u -n 502`.

I'd look at following places:

**Login items**

Go to System Preferences->Users & Groups. Choose appropriate user and select Login Items tab.

Look if you recognize uninstalled applications in the list and delete them. You have to select the app and press '-' beneath the list.

**Launchd**

Start the terminal. Enter `launchctl list` and see if you find uninstalled apps in there. False entries can be removed by `launchctl remove label`, for example `launchctl remove de.novamedia.NML2NDeviceObserver`.

Repeat the process, but this time prepend `sudo` to commands, like `sudo launchctl list`, to catch all the apps executed in system context.

You can find out more about launchd and launchctl by entering `man launchd` and `man launchctl`.

**Launchd configurations**

Look into following directories (from `man launchctl`):

1. `~/Library/LaunchAgents` - Per-user agents provided by the user
2. `~/Library/LaunchAgents` - Per-user agents provided by the administrator
3. `/Library/LaunchDaemons` - System wide daemons provided by the administrator.
4. `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` - OS X Per-user agents
5. `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` - OS X System wide daemons

If you find a file referring to uninstalled app, remove it (you'll need to `sudo rm` for items in 3, 4 & 5).

More about those files in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html especially 'The launchd Startup Process'.

Comment: Add /Library/LaunchAgents und /Library/LaunchDaemons to your list and be aware of different content for normal user and root ;-)

Comment: I focused on user context because that was pointed in console entry you wrote. But, you're right, the answer should be broader. So I did it. Is it written clear enough?